# What is the meaning of "She glanced mechanically at the house oppiste" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "She glanced mechanically at the house oppiste" in the following sentences (Source: Of human bondage by W. Somerset Maugham),

> The day broke gray and dull. The clouds hung heavily, and there was a
>   rawness in the air that suggested snow. A woman servant came into a
>   room in which a child was sleeping and drew the curtains. **She glanced
>   mechanically at the house oppsite**, a stucco house with portico, and
>   went to the child's bed.

?

Does it mean "A woman servant came into a room and drew the curtains. She glanced through the window of the room mechanically at the house that is opposite (===> the house opposite is not the house with a room in which a child was sleeping but another different house in which a child was not sleeping) ?

Whose house did a woman servant look at? Did she look at the house with a room in which a child was sleeping? Or did she look at someone else's house, not the house with a room in which a child was sleeping (==> figure A) but someone else's house(==> figure B)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, what is the opposite of a house?  A tomb? A hole in the ground? The surface of a ball?

There's no opposite of a house - and generally, nouns don't have opposites.

Fortunately, there's an entirely different meaning of *opposite* being used here:

> **opposite**
>
> being in a position on the other side; facing:
>
> *The two settlements are on opposite sides of the river.*
>   *We’re in the building opposite the gas station*.
>   *She asked the man sitting opposite if she could borrow his newspaper.*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/opposite

The woman came into the room, drew the curtains, and looked mechanically at the house directly across the street.

Comment: If so, she look at someone else's house that is directly across the street(==> figure B) ? In a case of a hotel, if we open the window of a room, we can see a corridor of a hotel that is opposite the room, a structure of a hotel that is opposite the room etc. Is it not possible to use those words in such a case (for example, She entered a room of the hotel. She open the window. she glanced at the hotel oppsite (==> the hotel where she is staying. the hotel is opposite the room where she  is staying).?)

Comment: @user22046, if you're in a hotel and you look at the hotel opposite you, across the hall from you, under you, above you (or any other phrase that describes a relative position), it always implies a different hotel. If I'm in a hotel room and I "look at the hotel across the corridor," I am looking at a different hotel.  If you want to refer to the same hotel and use a phrase that describes a relative position, you can say something like, "She went into the hotel room and looked at *the part of* the hotel across the corridor."